# Проверка строки. Является ли данная строка символов формулой алгебры высказываний или нет

Tags: c#

шаг 1. Проверка скобочного итога формулы.
шаг 2. Создать образы формул из правил 2 и 3.
шаг 3. Начиная с самого внутреннего вхождения скобок произвести проверку, является ли она формулой, путем сравнения с образом. Если результат проверки положительный, то заменить ее пропозициональной переменной.
шаг 4. Продолжать шаг 3, пока не будет получена одна пропозициональная переменная.

Формула логики высказываний определяется индуктивно следующим образом:

1. Любая высказывательная (пропозициональная) переменная, а также константы И, Л  есть формула.
2. Если A и B – формулы, то  А!A,AvB,A^B,A->B,A~B  есть  формулы.

---

**Вопрос такой**. Как создать "образы формул" из шага 2, чтобы находить эти образы в строке и заменять на переменную?

Comment: У вас в задании по сути описана грамматика для парсера. Напишите парсер по этой грамматике.

Comment: какой результат работы должен быть? true/false? или какая-то строка?

Comment: @Grundy Если есть формула в строке, то строка заменяется на переменную. Если формулы нет, то просто выдаёт введённую строку.